# Cluster algorithm to group events in more general domains

Tags: python, clustering, lda

I've a list of 1,300 news events, represented by only three terms coming from running LDA topic model on thousands of tweets. Here's some of them as an example:

```
['manchester,bony,city', 'attack,claims,responsibility', 'police,officers,nypd',
 'goal,arsenal,liverpool', 'test,pakistan,sunday', 'obama,ukraine,merkel', ...]
```

I need to group them in more general domains (Politics, Sport, Health, Economy, etc.).

Which kind of clustering algorithms could I use (in Python)?

Or maybe, can I use LDA topic model, even if I don't have documents but only three words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some creative post-processing can be done. For instance applying [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) and simplify some parts (**Manchester** is a **City**). Using Knowledge Graph Analysis also gives some meta-info e.g. mapping your word to Wikipedia graph or using DBpedia may help you to recognize Named Entitiy categories (**[Obama](http://dbpedia.org/page/Barack_Obama)** and **[Merkel](http://dbpedia.org/page/Angela_Merkel)** are politicians and NER does not necessarily capture their profession).

Note that the combination of named entity recognition and knowledge-base (Wikipedia, DBpedia, etc.) mapping is called [Entity Linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking).

Regardless of statistical learning for NLP techniques, all structures above are actually [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) so they can [give you also the semantic similarity measure](https://github.com/gsi-upm/sematch) based on which you can use other clustering algorithms like [Spectral Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering) and go to a semantically higher level of clustering.

Hope it helps :)